# How to serialize AMF responses using AMFPHP?

Tags: php, serialization, gateway, amf, amfphp

I've tried using a method I've seen and editing it to fit my environment.

> require_once( 'amfphp/core/amf/app/Gateway.php'); require_once(
>   AMFPHP_BASE . 'amf/io/AMFSerializer.php');
>
> $data = array('message' => 'Hello, world!')
>
> $serializer = new AMFSerializer(); $serializer->writeAmf3Data( $data
>   );
>
> print $serializer->outBuffer;

But nothing seems to work for me. Anyone know how to go about serializing AMF using AMFPHP without the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

With Amfphp 2.2.1 :

```
require_once( 'Amfphp/ClassLoader.php');
$serializer = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Serializer();
$message = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Message('/1/onResult', null, $data);
$packet = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Packet();
$packet->messages[] = $message;
echo $serializer->serialize($packet);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's actually coming out as AMF now. But I'm not sure I'm inputting the data the correct way because it's just saying "Header" and "Body" in the AMF response. Any help with that? :/

Comment: If you the serializer like this $data should be an AMF packet. https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Packet.php. So create a packet, create a message https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Message.php, and put your data in the message and the message in the packet.

Comment: `<? header('Content-type: application/x-amf'); 
require_once( 'Amfphp/ClassLoader.php'); 
$serializer = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Serializer(); 
$packet = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Packet('', array('message' => 'Hello, world!'), 3); 
$message = new Amfphp_Core_Amf_Message(/1/onResult', null, $packet); 
echo $serializer->serialize($message); ?>`
So am I on the correct track? Still says "Header" and "Body" in the response though. But I would like to know if I'm getting there?